If I never offer anything or never level up the statues of genshin impact, will it still considered as shirk for Muslim?
If I never offer anything or never level up the statues of genshin impact, will it still considered as shirk for Muslim? But I will only unlock the statues to teleport that place. And I might resonant with geo, anemo, etc elements by using the statue. Genshin impact is really so unique and beautiful game that i really want to play sometimes when I feel bored. ( You people may mention about the gatcha system of this game but I know it and as long as I am not spending my real money so I don't think it as gambling, so please don't tell me about this )
Please tell me what I actually asked if you have played genshin impact and of course only Muslim people should answer my question.
